# Drop all traffic and forward traffic from one port to another with iptables

Tags: iptables

I have 2 question with iptables:

1. How do I drop all input UDP traffic and port 53?

`Iptables –A INPUT –p udp –m udp --dport 53 -j DROP` is correct?

2 . How to forward all traffic from one port to another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do I drop all input UDP traffic and port 53?

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j DROP
```

How to forward all traffic from one port to another?

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport $srcPort -j REDIRECT --to-port $dstPort
```

For more info, [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-port-redirection-with-iptables/)

Comment: thanks mate, know, how can i check if this rules are working correctly?

Comment: @sorianoasir Hmmmmm using some VM or enabling a port listener like `nc` and connect from other computer.